# scrape blocks of data from webpage API

Tags: python, json, regex, beautifulsoup

I try to collect block data which forms a small table from a webpage. Pls see my codes below.

`

```
import requests
import re
import json
import sys
import os
import time
from lxml import html,etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.investing.com/instruments/OptionsDataAjax'
params = {'pair_id': 525, ## SPX
          'date': 1536555600, ## 2018-9-4
          'strike': 'all', ## all prices
          'callspots': 'calls',#'call_andputs',
          'type':'analysis', # webpage viewer
          'bringData':'true',
          }
headers = {'User-Agent': Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
def R(text, end='\n'): print('\033[0;31m{}\033[0m'.format(text), end=end)
def G(text, end='\n'): print('\033[0;32m{}\033[0m'.format(text), end=end)
page = requests.get(url, params=params,headers = headers)
if page.status_code != 200:
    R('ERROR CODE:{}'.format(page.status_code))
    sys.exit
    G('Problem in connection!')
else:
    G('OK')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
spdata = json.loads(soup.text)
print(spdata['data'])`
```

This result--spdata['data'] gives me a str, I just want to get following blocks in this str. There are many such data blocks in this str with the same format.

```
    SymbolSPY180910C00250000
    Delta0.9656
    Imp Vol0.2431
    Bid33.26
    Gamma0.0039
    Theoretical33.06
    Ask33.41
    Theta-0.0381
    Intrinsic Value33.13
    Volume0
    Vega0.0617
    Time Value-33.13
    Open Interest0
    Rho0.1969
    Delta / Theta-25.3172
```

I use json and BeautifulSoup here, maybe regular expression will help but I don't know much about re. To get the result, any approach is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your code:

```
regex = r"((SymbolSPY[1-9]*):?\s*)(.*?)\n[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*"
for match in re.finditer(regex, spdata['data'], re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
    for line in match.group().splitlines():
        print (line.strip())
```

Outputs

```
OK
SymbolSPY180910C00245000
Delta0.9682
Imp Vol0.2779
Bid38.26
Gamma0.0032
Theoretical38.05
Ask38.42
Theta-0.0397
Intrinsic Value38.13
Volume0
Vega0.0579
Time Value-38.13
Open Interest0
Rho0.1934
Delta / Theta-24.3966


SymbolSPY180910P00245000
Delta-0.0262
Imp Vol0.2652
...
```